# OnClick not Working on Ios11

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, click, ios11

I have the following function working on any devices except ios 11 and don't know why,
I have tried some solutions found here but it doesnt work, like : change the selector, add 'cursor:pointer' style, set an empty onclick before the function, without success.

Any idea why its this happening (or not happening),

This is the js code

```
    $('#buy-mobile-buttons-section').delegate('.buy-button', 'click', function(data) {
    alert('E');
    var $self = $(this);
    addToCart($(this), function(data){
        if (data > 0){
            addGMTAddToCart($self);
            var url = Routing.generate('pcc_cart_detail');
            $(location).attr("href", url);
        }
    });

});
```

and this is the HTML

```
<button type="button" data-loading-text="Añadiendo..." id="js-buy-button-mobile" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg buy GTM-addToCart buy-button"
    data-name="Asus K541UA-GO1205T Intel Core i7-7500U/8GB/1TB/15.6&quot;" 
    data-id="134853" data-price="633.49" data-brand="Asus"
    data-category="Portátiles" data-qty="1">
    <strong>Buy</strong>
    <i class="pccom-icon">]</i>
```

I hope you can understand it, my english is no the best arround here

Comment: Have you tried `on()` instead of `delegate()`?

Comment: which version of jquery you're using because `.delegate()` has been deprecated. It was superseded by the `.on()` method since` jQuery 1.7`

Comment: @PankajMakwana Yes I tried to change the selector to '#js-buy-button-mobile' and change it to on():
  $(document).on('click', '#js-buy-button-mobile', function(){
 //code
})

But still not working

Comment: @Curiousdev jQuery 3.2.1, But tried the on() method instead and same result

Comment: how you have used `on` show your code so i can see what's exactly the problem is. another thing i'm not able to find button with id `buy-mobile-buttons-section` in your code above id is `js-buy-button-mobile` might be  this thing you have missed

Comment: @Curiousdev This is the on() version :

https://plnkr.co/edit/S6vPIflGTrnQ7Z3aRazD?p=preview
It works in any devices but not ios11

Answer (score 1):

Try jquery bind function.

for example:

```
$( "#foo" ).bind( "click", function() {
    alert( "User clicked on 'foo.'" );
});
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18830633)

Comment: sory my bad. i fixed it with a suggestion now

Comment: Tried but the result its the same, works on any device but still not working in iOS

Comment: did you look this link  https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/134 .
it seems these guys have the same problem with ios