# Vue 2.6 not working correctly on Safari IOS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, safari, mobile-safari

i have a button that when is **clicked/pressed** will trigger a **click()** on a input **type=file** and allow the user to upload a file, it works fine on every platform, but sometimes i need to make a request before opening the upload window, when i need to make the request it work on every platform except on **Safari/IOS Safarai**, in **Safari** the request is made and i get the response but doesn’t trigger the input click().

Here is my code.

```
  async handleClickUpload(origin: string) {
    try {
      this._setDocumentType({ origin });
      const { code: documentCode } = this.currentDocument;

      if (this._isDocumentBackVariant(documentCode)) {
        await this._variantBackDocumentHandler();
      }
      this._handleUploadMethod();
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
```

Here i make the request and set the variation of the document, (**it work fine on the Safari**)

```
  async _variantBackDocumentHandler() {
    const { variation } = await this.getSpecificDocument("cnh_rg_frente");

    console.error("Encontrou variação", variation);
    if (!variation) {
      this._setDocumentType({ open: true });
      throw new Error("Variação não encontrada");
    }
    this._setDocumentType({ variation });
  }
```

On this method i choose if i open the user camera or allow the user to upload files, (**working fine on Safari**).

```
  _handleUploadMethod() {
    const { origin = "" } = this.documentType;
    if (origin === "camera") {
      this.cameraController.open = true;
    } else {
      this._uploadInputHandler();
    }
  }
```

Here i trigger the click of a hidden input, i have consoled the const uploadInput and it get the element (even in safari). On every browser it will trigger the click() and open a window to upload the file, **but on Safari nothing happens**.

```
  _uploadInputHandler() {
    const uploadInput: HTMLInputElement | null = document.querySelector("#uploadInput");

    uploadInput?.click();
  }
```

Here is my input

```
    <input
      id="uploadInput"
      @change="(event) => $emit('receiveFile', event)"
      type="file"
      style="visibility: hidden"
      accept="application/pdf, image/png, image/jpeg"
    />
```

Here is my .browserlistrc

```
defaults
not IE 11
maintained node versions
last 10 ios_saf versions
last 10 safari versions
```

Here is my babel.config.js

```
const plugins = () => {
  const defaultPlugins = [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-throw-expressions",
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      {
        absoluteRuntime: false,
        corejs: false,
        helpers: true,
        regenerator: true,
        useESModules: false,
      },
    ],
  ];
  // if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  //   defaultPlugins.push("transform-remove-console");
  // }
  return defaultPlugins;
};

module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      "@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset",
      {
        polyfills: [
          "es.array.iterator",
          "es.promise",
          "es.object.assign",
          "es.promise.finally",
          "es.symbol",
        ],
      },
    ],
  ],
  plugins: plugins(),
};
```

And i have the theses two import on my main.ts

```
import "core-js/stable";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
```

The method is working fine on every browser, but when i need to make the request before the click() nothing happens on IOS Safari, on others browser it works.

Answer (score 5):

It's a [known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65126364/javascript-on-click-not-working-in-ios-14).

Safari, in the name of *security*, does not register `click` events on elements with:

- `visibility: hidden;`
- `opacity: 0`
- `display: none`
- or which are not a "valid click target" - this is a loose concept they keep toying with but, for example, they don't consider an `<a>` without a `href` attribute a valid click target. Which means clicks on `<a href>` work, but on `<a>` do not. The `undefined` `href` adds validity to the click target, by Apple standards.

If you want the user to be able to click on an "invisible" element, don't give that element `visibility: hidden`. Instead, change its opacity to `0.01`.

Side-note: your issue is not Vue related. It can be repro-ed in React, Angular or plain JS. You might want to change the title to *"Web not working correctly in Safari IOS"*.